# How to retrieve data of a particular user after validation form MySQL using only Jdbc?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

This is a code snippet.......I just wanted it to retrieve information of a user after successful login validation of that user.....(I am only using jdbc and Mysql server and I am taking input from console....and assume that database table has 4 entries of your choice.)

Table Name:**Result**

My table Attributes are: **Name|  Roll|  Math|  Physics| Chemistry**

```
package com.connect.register;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import static com.connect.register.Dbconnection.*;

public class ShowResult {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PAS);
    System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

    String SQL = "Select * from studentconnect.result Where Roll=?";

    System.out.println("Creating statement...");
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter roll no. to see result:");
    int roll = scn.nextInt();
    scn.close();
    stmt.setInt(1, roll);

    rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("Login Successfull");
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please enter Correct roll no.");
    }
    **while (rs==roll) {
        // Retrieve by column name
        String Name = rs.getString("Name");
        int Roll = rs.getInt("Roll");
        int Math = rs.getInt("Math");
        int Physics = rs.getInt("Physics");
        int Chemistry = rs.getInt("Chemistry");
        // Display values
        System.out.println("Name: " + Name);
        System.out.println("Roll: " + Roll);
        System.out.println("Math " + Math);
        System.out.println("Physics: " + Physics);
        System.out.println("Chemistry: " + Chemistry);
    }
    rs.close();**

}
```

}

Comment: You need to provide more details about what you want to do. And please: if you post code, make sure it makes sense; the last part of your code (which you seem to have wanted to highlight given the presence of `**`), does not really clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: In last part of the code...i wanted to fetch data from mysql...
But it is not happening....

Comment: Because of that only ....i have given this code....

Comment: What more info do you nedd?

Comment: Well, `rs` never equal to `role` as `rs` is a `ResultSet` and `role` is an `int`, so of course that doesn't work. Which is why I assumed it wasn't your real code. Maybe you should learn the basics of Java and follow a few tutorials on JDBC first. But the information you need to provide: describe in words, what you want your code to do.

Comment: I have got the answer from....another site...
Thanks for helping....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned before, rs is completely different to roll. rs represents the ResulSet containing all responds to the query, you have sent to the db.
As you have entered the roll number already in the statement and I assume, a roll number is unique, your code can look like this:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
if ( rs.next()) {
  System.out.println("Login successfull");
  System.out.println("Name: " + rs.getString("Name") + "\n"
                   + "Roll: " + rs.getInt("Roll") + "\n"
                   + "Math: " + rs.getInt("Math") + "\n"
                   + "Physics: + rs.getInt("Physics") + "\n"
                   + "Chemistry: " + rs.getInt("Chemistry"));
  rs.close();    
} else {
  System.out.println("Please enter Correct roll no.");
}
```